# .htaccess doesn't redirect my pages from HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: seo, htaccess, redirects, 301-redirect, https

It seems like .htaccess doesn't redirect my pages from http to https. 
My domain is redirected to https but not my pages… Can it be a bad configuration from my web host?

Here is what I have done until now:

- Choose a SSL certificate and installed it on my website from the host.
- Force wp-config to pass from HTTP to HTTPs with: define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
- Tranform all of my URLs to HTTPs with Replace and Search DB
- Add this domain to Google Search Console…

Put this code in my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
# Redirect to HTTPS 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http://example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off [OR]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
# Redirect from www HTTPS to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I think that's all… Would you have an idea of what can cause this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http://example\.com [NC]
> ```

The `HTTP_HOST` variable contains just the *hostname*, not the *scheme* + *hostname*, so this will never match. If this never matches then it will never redirect `http://example.com/...` to HTTPS. (However, you have used this correctly in your *second* rule block which *will* redirect `http://www.example.com/...` to HTTPS.)

I assume you only have one domain? In which case, that directive should simply be removed (not corrected).

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off [OR]
> ```

However, you also have an erroneous `OR` flag on the last `RewriteCond` directive. If the preceding condition(s) matched then this would result in a redirect loop, since it's essentially `<condition> OR true`, which is *always* true.

### Summary

> ```
> # Redirect to HTTPS 
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http://example\.com [NC]
> RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$ [OR]
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off [OR]
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
> ```

So, in summary, you should replace the first rule block (above) with the following:

```
# Redirect to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

There's no point checking both `SERVER_PORT` *and* `HTTPS`. Either should be sufficient; not both.

Comment: Thank you very much, it work ! You are totally right, I am new to .htaccess and I didn't see this mistakes, even after several hours… Thank you also for your explanations. It's much clearer now. :)